# Is there a tool where you can edit a .NET dll directly?

Tags: .net, dll

Is there a tool where you can edit a .NET dll directly? .net reflector allows you to view the dll but doesn't allow you to modify it directly.

Comment: To those who marked this question off topic: I understand why; I also hope that you recognize that this question is the top Google search result for this issue.  Further, the contributors are, myself excluded, very high reputation contributors, suggesting that this is an advanced programming concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Reflexil](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/reflexil.aspx)

Comment: I knew about Reflexil but did not know how to use it properly. Thanks for the excellent link.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/releases).  After hours tinkering with Reflexil to no avail, I discovered dnSpy and solved my problem in 5 minutes.

It elegantly integrates the decompiler, assembly editor, and hex editor, allowing you to make very specific changes, even in assemblies that won't recompile (due to obfuscation, signing, etc).

Comment: Thank you, that was it! With dnSpy I was able to make improvements to a closed source library that wouldn't have found their way into it otherwise. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)

Comment: Reflexil is using Mono.cecil.